# Retrieve all document libraries in a SharePoint Site with Search

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-search

I would like to retrieve all document libraries with the help of SharePoint(2010/2016) Search in a site.

I am using FQL and when I tried below I got all lists in particular site. Is this the right approach or is there a better approach for the same.

```
<QueryPacket xmlns='urn:Microsoft.Search.Query'>
    <Query>
        <SupportedFormats>
            <Format revision='1'>urn:Microsoft.Search.Response.Document:Document</Format>
        </SupportedFormats>
        <Context>
            <QueryText language='en' type='FQL'>and(filter(path:string(\"/Forms/AllItems.aspx\")),sitename:string(\"http://host/sitename\"))</QueryText>
        </Context>
        <ResultProvider>FASTSearch</ResultProvider>
        <Range><Count>10</Count></Range>
    </Query>
</QueryPacket>
```

Above approach is working fine in SharePoint 2010 but when I do the same in SharePoint 2016 it does not give any records. I would like to search "/Forms/AllItems.aspx" value in path field. It's working if I give the absolute URL but not for relative URL.

You can refer to below link on how to create test project for FQL.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg588339(v=office.14).aspx

**EDIT(17-Nov)**

As per @Lee_MSFT's response I tried my search criteria with "ContentClass:STS_List_DocumentLibrary" and it returns only document libraries. Because I need to search in the specific library, I added an additional filter for SiteName and it gave me the result but not all library.

So I tried below criteria with different properties but none of them gave me all libraries in a site.

> SiteName:"http://site" ContentClass:"STS_List_DocumentLibrary
>   SPSiteURL:"http://site" ContentClass:"STS_List_DocumentLibrary"
>   Path:"http://site" ContentClass:"STS_List_DocumentLibrary"

Because none of above worked I tried below to see if I can get the document library that I am interested in and surprisingly got the record.

> Path:"https://site/Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx"
>   ContentClass:"STS_List_DocumentLibrary"

So looks like when I search path with the absolute URL I get the library but when I try to search all library with contentclass it's not returning all libraries.

Comment: Late comment: To filter for a site, use an asterix/wildcard at the end of the path: `Path:"https://site/*" ContentClass:"STS_List_DocumentLibrary"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could check the property contentclass:STS_List_DocumentLibrary.

One link for your reference:

http://avalagopi767.blogspot.sg/2016/02/sharepoint-2013-keyword-query-kql.html

Comment: If I am not wrong then this will return all documents with content type document library. I need list of all document libraries within a specific site.

Comment: Nope, this works perfectly to return the AllItems view for every Doc Lib you have access to.

Comment: @RaviKhambhati so filter it by the specific site as well.  There’s no reason why you cannot use more than one filter

Comment: @Lee_MSFT content class approach worked but run into some other issue. Please have a look at the updated question.

Comment: @MatthewMcDermott What if we don't want to return AllItems view, but another custom view for the document library, is that possible? Almost like filter it out...

Comment: I don't think that is possible without changing up the display template.